# how to find the machine has bluetooth?

Tags: windows, bluetooth

how to find the machine has blue tooth on vista  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a Bluetooth icon in Control Panel if it's available.

You can also check device manager for bluetooth devices (Start -> type **devmgmt.msc** in the search -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: is it correct ?  because if we didn't install the blue tooth also it will show like this ?

Comment: That just means it's available on your machine. If there are devices that means you have them installed/plugged in.

Comment: but in machine has blue tooth symbol . but its not showing here.. now what to do ?

Comment: If there is no bluetooth device in device manager you probably don't have any installed & attached.